# Ajax control not working after postback

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, ajaxform

I am having a developed application and everything works perfectly in visual studio 2010 in local machine.but when I deploy my application in IIS7 classic pool mode, the ajax controls are working fine initially.But once postback is happening none of the of Ajax controls are working?
Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by none of them are working?

Shot in the dark, you are likely removing and reloading dom elements that you bound to events previously.  Once the new dom elements are loaded you will need to rebind any events such as click to them at that point.